# Get value from dict where key is value another list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, unix, set

I want to extract the value from dict where key matches another list

```
l_dict = {"oc1":"tar1", "oc2":"tar2", "oc3":"tar3", "oc4":"tar4","oc5":"tar5"}
l_list = ["oc3", "oc5"] 

ld = set(l_dict)
ll = set(l_list)

for i in ld.intersection(ll):
    print("Element "+i+" was found")
```

I get :

```
Element oc3 was found. 
Element oc5 was found.
```

I really need an output with tar values from dict, i.e, :

```
tarfiles = ['tar3', 'tar5']
```

How can I get it?

Comment: tarfiles = [l_dict[key] for key in l_list]

Comment: Are keys of l_list  ALL in the dict ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of printing, save the corresponding value

```
tars = []
for i in ld.intersection(ll):
    tars.append(l_dict[i])
```

---

Note that is all strings from `l_list` are keys of `l_dict` just do

```
tars = [l_dict[key] for key in l_list]
```

Comment: thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
tarfiles = [l_dict[key] for key in l_list]
```

if there are items in l_list that are not keys in l_dict use:

```
tarfiles = [l_dict[key] for key in l_list if key in l_dict]
```

Comment: thank you so much!